# Node JS: How can I pass arguments to promise resolve/reject from promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, arguments

This code works, I just need help with argument passing.

**Goal:**

To pass arguments to promises while iterating through a for loop. The arguments to pass are named `folder`, `subfolder`, `pastsearch`. The promises are called `p1` and `p2`

**What the Code does**

This code works. Each promise takes a search term, looks for it in
its file and returns "yes" or "non" if file is there or not.

Promise.all prints a single line of yes/non to a file and
prints the total count of "yes" to another file.

**CODE**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline')


const task_id = 1;

let folder = 1;
let subfolder = 1;
let pastsearch = 1;

const myarray = [6567, 50105, 67637, 293697];

const mylen = myarray.length;

const myfiles = ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt'];


fs.writeFile('/pathtomyfile/', '', function() {
  console.log('done')
})


fs.writeFile('/pathtomyfile/', '', function() {
  console.log('done')
})


const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let lineCount = 0;

  let v = 0;
  let yesnon = "non";

  let readStream = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('/pathtofile/round_' + task_id + '/threehundred_' + folder + '/' + subfolder + '/' + myfiles[0], 'utf8')
  });


  readStream.on("line", (line) => {
    lineCount++;

    if (line == pastsearch) {
      yesnon = "yes";

      v++;
    }

  });

  readStream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('end');
    readStream.destroy();
  });


  readStream.on("close", () =>
    resolve({
      yesnon
    })

  )
});

const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let readStream = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('/pathtofile/round_' + task_id + '/threehundred_' + folder + '/' + subfolder + '/' + myfiles[1], 'utf8')
  });

  let lineCount = 0;
  let v = 0;
  let yesnon = "non";

  readStream.on("line", (line) => {
    lineCount++;

    if (line == pastsearch) {
      yesnon = "yes";

      v++;
    }

  });


  readStream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('end');
    readStream.destroy();
  });


  readStream.on("close", () =>
    resolve({
      yesnon
    }))

});

for (let h = 0; h < 3; h++) {

  folder++
  subfolder++
  pastsearch = myarray[h];

  Promise.all([p1, p2]).then((results) => {

    const output = results.map(({
      yesnon
    }) => yesnon).join(' ');

    fs.appendFileSync('/pathtofile/plain_round' + task_id + '.txt', output + "\n", 'utf8');

    const output2 = results.map(({
      yesnon
    }) => yesnon);


    let count = 0;

    function countValues(array, countItem) {
      array.forEach(itm => {
        if (itm == countItem) count++;
      });

      return count;
    }
    const myresult34 = countValues(output2, "yes");


    fs.appendFileSync('/pathtofile/round' + task_id + '.txt', myresult34 + "\n", 'utf8');


  });
}
```

**Note:**

I am new to nodejs, mostly php experience, so I wrote this the best that I could from studying stackoverflow Q/A Posts.

Comment: @Barmer thanks for the edits, easier to read.

Comment: *"...pass arguments to promises"*: promises are objects, not functions.

Comment: @trincot Thank you for that important clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your promises in a function that takes `folder`, `subfolder`, and `pastsearch` as arguments. For example with `p1`:

```js
const p1 = (folder, subfolder, pastsearch)  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // `folder`, `subfolder` and `pastsearch` are available here
    }
}
```

Then invoke `p1` inside `Promise.all`:

```js
Promise.all([p1(folder, subfolder, pastsearch), p2]).then((results) => {
```

In javascript this technique is called [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I am getting a heap out of memory issue that I did not have before-- must my read write statements have to be rewritten in a different format to accommodate the addition of the closure? The readStream.destroy() statement is no longer working. For some reason closure is not allowing me to tell the write and read streams I have ended with the on end and destroy()...

Comment: The promise will be added to the `Promise.all` array just the same way, so it shouldn't cause an issue. I would guess that's an error caused by some other part of your refactor